# Why feof() returning 0 before any operation?

Tags: c

I wanted to know how excatly feof() works. I write some simple progrma to chek it out but results are far away from I expected. Here is a code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>




int main()
{

  FILE* infile = fopen("obrazek.bmp","r");

  int a;

  while (feof(infile) != 0)
  {

  fread(&a, sizeof(a),1, infile);

  //int n = feof(infile);

 printf("%i",a);

  };


 fclose(infile);

 return 0;
```

}

Why feof() return 0 if I only opened a file? How to easily checked that i hitted end of a random file?

Comment: Do you know what `feof()` returns and *why* it returns it ? And when you think you know the answer to that, read this: ["Why is while (!feof(file)) always wrong?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: Your logic is backwards. **[feof](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/feof/)** returns non-zero if it's EOF.

Comment: @WhozCraig sir , please also point to the almost-faq question. I seem to have messed up my bookmarks. can't find it

Comment: People usually post to ask why something is not working. It's rare that people ask why something does work.

Comment: @SouravGhosh in a pinch, just throw `[c] feof wrong` in the search box. =P

Comment: @jweyrich: Holy Grail! You have absolutley right :D. Thats te effect of lack of sleep . Thanks man :)

Comment: @susi33 I *strongly* advise you follow [that link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) and read more about it. Best of luck.

Comment: If there isn't a FAQ for C questions there should be. 1) Why isn't `feof()` working? 2) What is wrong with `a = a++ + --a * a++`?

Comment: Plus [another common mistake related to feof](http://c-faq.com/stdio/feof.html) - well, there's http://c-faq.com.

Comment: @susi33 in general, when something does not work the way you expect it to work, please read the documentation on that something before asking others for help. You might think it's faster to simply ask for help, but by taking that extra step you will develop your own abilities much further and faster.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of the 'Why `while (!feof(file))` is always wrong' question because the topics are exceptionally closely related.  An alternative is to close it as 'Off-topic / trivial typo'.

Comment: @susi33: Er... Why would anyone expect `feof` to return anything other than `0` immediately after opening the file???? Your question sounds like "Why `2+2` is suddenly `4`?" There's nothing "sudden" in `2+2` being `4`, as there's nothing unexpected in `feof` returning `0` in your case.

Comment: @AnT: 2+2 can actually be 5 for sufficiently large values of 2. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`feof` returns true (1) if you have previously attempted to read past the end of the file, and have not cleared it with `clearerr`.  When you first open the file and haven't read anything, you haven't read past the end, so it returns 0.

This behavior is why using `while(feof(infile) != 0)` is [almost always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).  Instead, you should check the return value of your `fread` call and use that to control the loop.

Comment: Note that the loop condition should be: `while (fread(&a, sizeof(a),1, infile) != 0)`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - No, because that code can't tell how many bytes were read.

Comment: Well, the code that it's replacing also can't tell. In any case, given the options to `fread()`, it'll either return 1 (meaning `sizeof(a)` bytes were read) or 0 (meaning some smaller number of bytes was read, or possibly EOF or something else went wrong). So it does know whether the read was successful or not, and if it's successful, it knows exactly how many bytes were read. It's an improvement over using `feof()` because it tests the function that fails, rather than assuming it will succeed. Alternatively, you can use `size_t nrecs; while ((nrecs = fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, infile)) != 0)`.